# SymPy: make assumption -> angle in a range

Tags: python, sympy

If I write in sympy:

```py
from sympy import sin, sqrt, symbols
t = symbols('t')
sqrt(sin(t)**2)
```

the output is:

```
sqrt(sin(t)**2)
```

How can I inform sympy that `t` is in the range `0..pi` so that `sqrt(sin(t)**2)` simplifies to `sin t`?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but you could do t % pi so that it will simplify, right?

Comment: What do you mean Peter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to telling SymPy that `sin(t)` is nonnegative. You can do this by replacing `sin(t)` with a nonnegative symbol to allow for the simplification to take place and then to restore the original value:

```py
>>> eq = sqrt(sin(t)**2)
>>> d=Dummy(nonnegative=True)
>>> eq.subs(sin(t), d).subs(d, sin(t))
sin(t)
```

Comment: It works. I hope there as a more elegant solution. Thank you!